# Object in texture mode looks like solid mode

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view

When I am in texture mode one of my objects looks like it is in solid mode. The model is textured like all other models in the scene, but it doesn't look like it is in texture mode.

Screenshot will explain better:

[image]

1. What this model looks like.
2. What all models should look like in texture mode.

Comment: Is it possible you've set it's *maximum draw type* to *solid* in *Properties > Object > Display*?

Comment: yes you are right thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that *Maximum draw type* is set to *Textured* in *Properties > Object > Display*:

[image]

<sup>*See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144627/30849) for a 2.8 screenshot.*</sup>

Comment: @Leander That's fine, thanks! I've gone ahead and reversed the duplicate as well, I think your answer is better than mine