# Objects stuck in solid mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

I can't figure out what is causing this I tried removing the materials for the objects as well as re-assigning new materials and flipping normals I don't know what is causing this issue for the model.

The head seems to be working like it should but the body doesn't turn white in textured mode or black in material mode. I'm using default blender render

[image: gif of it]

Comment: Select the stuck object and look at maximum draw type (object tab, in the display section).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Extending lemon's commented.</sup>

An object can be restricted to a lower display mode.

In [2.79](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/properties/display.html#display) it is set in the **Properties Panel** in the *Object* tab under the 
*Display* section.

[image: max draw type]

> The Maximum shading mode to display in the 3D View. This can be useful if you have a high-poly object that is slowing down performance.

In [2.8](http://Display%20As%20The%20shading%20mode%20to%20display%20in%20the%203D%20View;%20this%20can%20be%20useful%20if%20you%20have%20a%20high-poly%20object%20that%20is%20slowing%20down%20the%20viewport.) the term is ***Display As***.

[image: 2.8 term]